# How do I fix an issue with AutoCAD not recognizing commands?

Tags: autocad, cad

I'm currently experiencing a problem with AutoCAD where it won't recognize certain commands. For example, when I try to use the "Line" command, nothing happens when I type it into the command line or use the shortcut key. I've tried restarting the program and my computer, but the issue persists. Has anyone else experienced this problem before, and if so, how did you fix it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could always repair it (if supported) or reinstall.

Comment: AutoCAD comes with support, contact AutoDesk - unless you are using a hacked copy.